# Deserialize a BindingSource list without having two copies in memory?

Tags: c#, generics, serialization, bindingsource

My application's "document" is really just a BindingSource that has a List<>.  Since you cannot directly serialize a BindingSource, when it comes time to save, I serialize the List<>.

When it comes time to load, I'd like to deserialize straight into the BindingSource, but I do not thing you can (the .List member is read-only).  So I have to deserialize into a temporary list and then Add each of the items to the BindingSource's List.

This means that by the time I'm done there are two copies in memory, one of which will be cleaned up, but if the files get large that's going to be a problem.

Is there a more direct approach I should be taking, or some way to deserialize directly into the List that the BindingSource holds?

Rather than serializing the list I tried individually serializing the elements in the list, but the resulting disk file was much larger.

Answer (score 0):

If the size is big enough that holding it twice is an issue, then probably holding it once is an issue too. However; if you are interested, protobuf-net has a DeserializeItems method that returns a non-buffered (fully streaming) `IEnumerable<T>` - i.e. no list. So you could:

```
foreach(var item in {DeserializeItems})
    bindingSource.Add(item);
```

I can also pretty-much guarantee that it'll be smaller on disk and faster to process too.

I wonder, though, if "virtual mode" might be a better option for a large list.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Queue/Dequeue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c.aspx) to transport the from one list to another as data arrive